# Can someone help me to translate this function into sml?

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml, sml, smlnj

I've tried to translate this OCaml code

```
 type bool_expr =
    | Var of string
    | Not of bool_expr
    | And of bool_expr * bool_expr
    | Or of bool_expr * bool_expr;

let rec eval val_vars = function
    | Var x -> List.assoc x val_vars
    | Not e -> not(eval val_vars e)
    | And(e1, e2) -> eval val_vars e1 && eval val_vars e2
    | Or(e1, e2) -> eval val_vars e1 || eval val_vars e2
```

And here is what i did

```
 datatype bool_expr = Var of string
    | Not of bool_expr
    | And of bool_expr * bool_expr
    | Or of bool_expr * bool_expr;
    
And(Or(Var "a", Var "b"), And(Var "a", Var "b"));

val rec eval vars = 
    fn  Var x => List.assoc x vars
    | Not e => not(eval vars e)
    | And(e1, e2) => eval vars e1 andalso eval vars e2
    | Or(e1, e2) => eval vars e1 orelse eval vars e2
```

I got errors about vars on this line : 'val rec eval vars =', and i don't know the equivalent off 'List.assoc' in SML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate OCaml into SML by following [Comparing Objective Caml and Standard ML](http://adam.chlipala.net/mlcomp/).

Here is one attempt:

```ml
datatype bool_expr =
    Var of string
  | Not of bool_expr
  | And of bool_expr * bool_expr
  | Or of bool_expr * bool_expr

exception NotFound
fun lookup x [] = raise NotFound
  | lookup x ((y,v)::rest) =
      if x = y
      then v
      else lookup x rest

fun eval val_vars = fn
    Var x => lookup x val_vars
  | Not e' => not (eval val_vars e')
  | And (e1, e2) => eval val_vars e1 andalso eval val_vars e2
```

In SML, you wish to do the following:

- Use the `datatype` keyword to define an algebraic data type, rather than OCaml's `type`.
- Use `fn` instead of `function` for both anonymous functions in which you pattern match, as well as anonymous functions that just take an argument. (OCaml has `function` and `fun` as syntactic conveniences for anonymous functions where SML has just `fn`.)
- When listing constructors or pattern matching, do not prepend `|` in front of the first case.
- `&&` is called `andalso` and `||` is called `orelse`. (Note that `and` means something different.)
- There is no `List.assoc` so you have to make it.
- There is no `Not_found` exception so you have to make it.
- Use `fun` instead of `let rec` for recursive functions; while recursive functions *can* be defined using `val rec` this does not support parameters on the left-hand side of `=`, which it does in OCaml. So while you *could* write

  ```
  val rec eval = fn val_vars => fn e => case e of
      Var x => lookup x val_vars
    | Not e' => not (eval val_vars e)
    | And (e1, e2) => eval val_vars e1 andalso eval val_vars e2
    | Or (e1, e2) => eval val_vars e1 orelse eval val_vars e2
  ```

  this is less ergonomic.